# Block sharepoint central admin from internet and allow only intranet access

Tags: central-administration

I want to block sharepoint central admin access from internet and only allow intranet access. I don't see any where to configure this in central admin. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use your firewall to block it. This isn't a function of Central Admin or SharePoint.